# Perforce streams: Task streams usage

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I have a requirement to create a child stream which will pick only specific folders from `mainline`(parent) stream. While creating child stream, to achieve this I restrict the view by using `share/isolate/import` successfully able to create the child streams which only the code i am interested in.

But, I have gone through some tutorials on streams and found something on lightweight streams (task streams) which is used to create the streams partially from parent. In my scenario do i need to really use this `lightweight streams`? What is the main advantage & limitiations of using this light-weight streams over using normal approach as I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of task streams is not to create streams "partially" -- you have already done this with your `share/import` paths.  Don't fix what isn't broken!

Task streams are built to be short-lived and easily archive-able once the associated task is complete (via the "unload" command).  The limitations of task streams are described in the documentation here:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Content/P4V/streams.task.html

namely that they can't be reparented and they may not have children.  If you use task streams as short-lived single-task streams (as the name "task stream" implies, a task stream is for a single task), these limitations won't generally be a problem.  If you try to use a task stream as a development mainline, you're going to have problems.

If your development process involves creating a new branch for a short-term task (e.g. an individual hotfix parented to a particular branch), and you have a lot of these tasks, task streams may be useful due to their easy cleanup and low overhead (when a task stream is unloaded it's removed from the db, which means you don't accumulate db cruft over time as you create and abandon them).

If this does not sound like your development process, forget you ever heard about task streams.  Do not try to imagine ways that you can use task streams for things that aren't short-term tasks.  Hammers are suitable for nails.  Do not use them to try to drive screws, especially when you have a perfectly good screwdriver *right there* and are already using it successfully.

(Can you tell I've seen more than a few instances of people trying to use task streams for absolutely everything because they "sound cool"?  Resist the urge!)